# Error while installing apk in android 5.1?

Tags: android, apk

I am getting an Error while installing apk in android 5.1.

```
Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.acelrtech.apps.xxxxxxxxx-1
                                               com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: scanPackageLI
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageDirtyLI(PackageManagerService.java:6313)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5605)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installNewPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:10550)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:11128)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2800(PackageManagerService.java:241)
                                                   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$6.run(PackageManagerService.java:8993)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                   at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Here is the Gradle main part looks looks like . Hoping for a better input.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'         
defaultConfig {             
applicationId "com.acelrtech.apps.xxxxxxxxxxxx”                
minSdkVersion 14            
targetSdkVersion 21             
versionCode 23              
versionName "2016.6.21"             
generatedDensities = []             
multiDexEnabled true         }
```

Also i tried the this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805360/cant-install-android-studio-apk-on-my-phone) ..

Comment: hi are you added this line in app.gradle dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

Comment: yes added . but no effect.

Comment: pls follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html and your are using application class or not if yes then Note: If your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex. For more information, see the MultiDexApplication reference documentation.

Comment: That link is useful. In my case i cant able to set compileSdkVersion to 21 as per the doc. my app required min compileSdkVersion 22 . Any solution for this ...