# Can't install app from app store after changing to compileSdkVersion 23

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest

It seems that after updating my app to use compileSdkVersion 23 from 21, some users have started to complain that they are unable to install the app from the app store referencing error code 505.

I have looked at other people with install issues with error code 505 and a lot point to permission package name conflicts which arose with lollipop phones, but this would not explain why this problem only started to happen after updating my compileSdkVersion.  I also looked through my manifest and the only permission using a package name other than "android.permission" were:

```
<uses-permission android:name="[my package].permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

which both seem correct.  Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: When you install the release version of the app yourself (e.g., `adb install`), what do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not able to replicate the issue, so when I install locally it works.  I am just going off of increased reports by users encountering the issue.

Comment: You might try to change uses-permission to permission and you also can grab some ideas from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message

Comment: Hello Chriskot, same issue here... did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I haven't found a definitive solution yet.  There are lots of things on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues about random install issues, but nothing that has helped me yet.  I did find an issue on another app where if you are using a new version of google analytics and don't have "applicationId" specified in your manifest it can cause install issues. I'll keep you posted if I find any other solutions.

Comment: If you are using build tools 23.0.2 this could be your issue @Peter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781210/my-newly-released-app-cant-be-installed-error-code-504

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for the 505 error. The cause was a missing applicationId variable in my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx"
    }
}
```

Full story described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189079